# @objc override func insertReactSubview(_ subview: UIView!, at atIndex: Int) is not called iOS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, bridging-header

@objc override func insertReactSubview(_ subview: UIView!, at atIndex: Int)

I use the above method to pass `UIView` from reactnative to ios. But this method is not calling sometimes. Please help.